# VirtualBox and mounting Windows Drive

Tags: mount, virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit as my primary OS and I am planning to use Windows 7 Ultimate x64-bit OS in VirtualBox.

How I can mount Windows Drive to my VirtualBox (Oracle)?

Comment: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#gui-createvm

Comment: For all intents and purposes this question is about mounting a Windows drive on a Windows guest. This would likely be on-topic at http://superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a directory in your host OS as "shared folder".

From the Windows guest you can access it via "network".